# Woocommerce Editar URL de variable (endpoints) "My account Page"

Tags: woocommerce

Muy buenas tardes y gracias por leerme.
Estoy trabajando el diseño de una tienda online con wordpress y en pleno desarrollo de la página "Mi cuenta". Sucede que necesito editar/modificar las URL relacionada al endpoint de "edit address". 
Actualmente, cuando doy click al boton que me lleve a dicho endoint: "Editar Direcciones", el enlace se actualiza de: https://myvtechnologies.com/mi-cuenta/ a **https://myvtechnologies.com/mi-cuenta/editar-direcciones/** y si deseo editar la dirección de envío por ejemplo, la url se actualiza a **https://myvtechnologies.com/mi-cuenta/editar-direcciones/envio/**
Lo que deseo es editar la última URL, por ejemplo: https://myvtechnologies.com/mi-cuenta/editar-direcciones/envio/#edit, donde estaría aumentando #edit al final.

Desde ya agradezco sus respuestas.

Comment: Con endpoint, quice decir "Variables"

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Creo que la pregunta más directa sería: Usando JavaScript, ¿cómo podría crear un redireccionamiento de la web: https://myvtechnologies.com/mi-cuenta/editar-direcciones/envio/ a la web: https://myvtechnologies.com/mi-cuenta/editar-direcciones/envio/#edit, estoy agregando /#edit al final.